# Analyzer erroneously complains about something legit(?)

Tags: xcode, unix, llvm

Consider the following code fragment:

```
unichar* foo = (previously allocated);

unichar* bar = reallocf(foo, 0);
```

When I run Xcode's Analyze command, the call to reallocf() is flagged because of the second argument:

"Call to 'reallocf' has an allocation size of 0 bytes"

But the documentation for reallocf() says in part: "If size [the second argument] is zero and ptr is not NULL, a new, minimum sized object is allocated and the original object is freed." So my call to reallocf() should be perfectly legit, no?

Googling around a bit surfaced this comment attached to a patch made to LLVM:

"Warn about reallocf with an allocation size of 0, like realloc."

http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=166995

Seems like a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not illegal, it's just a likely error. That's what the analyzer is for. The analyzer gives the same warning for any of the allocation functions passed a 0 size. The [current source cites](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/lib/StaticAnalyzer/Checkers/UnixAPIChecker.cpp?revision=175679&view=markup#l220) secure coding standard [CERT MEM04-C](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/MEM04-C.+Do+not+perform+zero-length+allocations). The fear is that the program will later assume that a non-`NULL` pointer can be dereferenced and possibly written through, while the one returned from a zero-sized allocation can't be.